# SQL aggregate for a Week or Year

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I have a SQL query which goes like,

```
select  
    DATEPART (week, pos_date) as weeknr,
      Sum(redeem_count)* 100.0/Sum(issue_count) as incent_redemption_rate,
      pos_date
from incent_summary
group by pos_date
order by pos_date
```

I get output as follows

```
weeknr  incent_redemption_rate  pos_date
20  13.356164383561 2020-05-10 00:00:00.000
20  8.990536277602  2020-05-11 00:00:00.000
20  9.615384615384  2020-05-12 00:00:00.000
20  12.917271407837 2020-05-13 00:00:00.000
20  11.447811447811 2020-05-14 00:00:00.000
20  13.773314203730 2020-05-15 00:00:00.000
20  10.798650168728 2020-05-16 00:00:00.000
21  9.164420485175  2020-05-17 00:00:00.000
21  12.170087976539 2020-05-18 00:00:00.000
21  12.000000000000 2020-05-19 00:00:00.000
21  12.932330827067 2020-05-20 00:00:00.000
21  13.464447806354 2020-05-21 00:00:00.000
21  11.248073959938 2020-05-22 00:00:00.000
21  13.868613138686 2020-05-23 00:00:00.000
22  16.559485530546 2020-05-24 00:00:00.000
22  12.602739726027 2020-05-25 00:00:00.000
22  11.559888579387 2020-05-26 00:00:00.000
22  11.176470588235 2020-05-27 00:00:00.000
```

What I actually intend to do is aggregate `incent_redemption_rate` by week, so I just need 1 record for week number 20 and not multiple, actually the start date of week 20.

Comment: Then, group it by week, not date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the weekly inception rate and then show the starting date of the week i.e. Monday. One way of doing this is getting the weekly inception rate for each week like below and then join it with main table to get pos date.

```
SELECT pos_date,wkly_rate.weeknr, wkly_rate.incent_redemption_rate
FROM incent_summary ins
JOIN (SELECT DATEPART(week, pos_date) as weeknr,
         SUM(redeem_count)* 100.0/Sum(issue_count) as incent_redemption_rate
      FROM incent_summary
      GROUP BY DATEPART(week, pos_date) ) wkly_rate ON wkly_rate.weeknr = DATEPART(week, ins.pos_date)
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,A.pos_date) = 'Monday'
```

However, what you are doing in your query is that you are getting inception rate for each day instead of week and then you can just get for one day i.e Monday using the below query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 
        DATEPART(week, pos_date) as weeknr,
        SUM(redeem_count)* 100.0/Sum(issue_count) as incent_redemption_rate,
        pos_date
      FROM incent_summary
      GROUP BY pos_date
 ) A
 WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,A.pos_date) = 'Monday'
 ORDER BY pos_date
```

Answer (score 1):

To get data on a weekly basis, just change your query to group by `weeknr` (using its formula as you can't group by a column alias) and take the `MIN` of `pos_date` to get the first day of the week:

```
SELECT
      DATEPART (week, pos_date) as weeknr,
      SUM(redeem_count)* 100.0/SUM(issue_count) AS incent_redemption_rate,
      MIN(pos_date)
FROM incent_summary
GROUP BY DATEPART (week, pos_date)
ORDER BY DATEPART (week, pos_date)
```